# How do I optimize checking for any added, deleted or updated items on a list with Linq to Objects?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects

I need to check whether or not any operation (insert, delete or update) happened on items existing on a generic collection. I have a list with the original objects and a list with the new ones. The references for two objects with the same Id won't be the same.

Right now I was able to solve the problem, but with 3 operations being executed. Here's my code:

```
var oldList = new List<MyClass>();
var newList = new List<MyClass>();

//Search for items on the new list that are not present on the old one
var addedItems = newList.Where(item => !oldList.Select(x => x.Id).Contains(item.Id));

//Search for items on the old list that are not present on the new one
var deletedItems = oldList.Where(item => !newList.Select(x => x.Id).Contains(item.Id));

//Search for items present on both lists, but with any property changed
var updatedItems = from x in oldList
                   join y in newList on x.Id equals y.Id
                   where x.Name != y.Name ||
                         x.Description != y.Description ||
                         x.Quantity != y.Quantity
                   select new { OriginalEntity = x, NewEntity = y };

bool anyChanges = addedItems.Count() > 0   ||
                  deletedItems.Count() > 0 ||
                  updatedItems.Count() > 0;
```

This code works, but I would like to know if it's possible to achieve the result in a cleaner or faster (less operations) way.

I know I could implement IEquatable<T> on MyClass but please consider that this is not possible for now (only because I want to find out if there's a solution for when that really isn't possible). In any case, that would allow me to use "Except" and detect easily inserts or deletes but not updates (unless I'm missing something).

Also, I just wanted to point out that there is a lot of questions on SO with similar questions but I haven't found any related to detect insert, delete and update simultaneously (reason why I'm posting this).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you also check ObservableCollection?

Comment: Do you just need to return a bool to indicate if the 2 lists are equal?

Comment: @MikeHixson Yes, i just need a bool to indicate if there's any change of any kind on the newer list is comparison with the first.

Comment: @MichelKeijzers I just checked ObservableCollection. I haven't used but MSDN states that it can detect inserts, deletes or when the list is refreshed. So, doesn't mention changes to properties of the objects on the list. I would have to test it.

Comment: @user1677919 I'm sure it does not check for property changes, but you might add it manually, with the INotify(Property) mechanism; but I think that is more related to WPF/XAML, not sure if you can also use it independently.

Answer (score 1):

Mostly you just need caching + better data structures.

```
var oldList = new List<MyClass>();
var newList = new List<MyClass>();

// O(1) lookups vs O(N) lookups
var oldListIds = new HashSet<int>(oldList.Select(x => x.Id));
var newListIds new HashSet<int>(newList.Select(x => x.Id));

//Search for items on the new list that are not present on the old one
var addedItems = newList.Where(item => !oldListIds.Contains(item.Id));

//Search for items on the old list that are not present on the new one
var deletedItems = oldList.Where(item => !newListIds.Contains(item.Id));

//Search for items present on both lists, but with any property changed
var updatedItems = from x in oldList
                   join y in newList on x.Id equals y.Id
                   where x.Name != y.Name ||
                         x.Description != y.Description ||
                         x.Quantity != y.Quantity
                   select new { OriginalEntity = x, NewEntity = y };

// Use .Any() instead of .Count() so we stop after first item
bool anyChanges = addedItems.Any()   ||
                  deletedItems.Any() ||
                  updatedItems.Any();
```

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this:

```
// determines if evey item in listA has as a match in listB
static bool Matches(List<MyClass> listA, List<MyClass> listB)
{
    var matches = listA.GroupJoin(listB, a => a.Id, b => b.Id,
        (a, b) => b.Any(c => c.Name == a.Name && c.Description == a.Description && c.Quantity == a.Quantity));

    return matches.All(m => m);
}
```

This does a GroupJoin() returning a bool if B joins with A. Then it does All() to see if all joins return true.

Then you could call it like this:

```
bool equal = Matches(oldList, newList) && Matches(newList, oldList);
```

This returns a bool indicating if everything in oldList joins to something newList **AND** everything in newList joins to something in oldList.

I'm not sure if this will be faster than the other suggestions, but it certainly is less code.